# Assigning object to instance variable during iteration

Tags: coffeescript

I'm using this peculiar syntax for assigning an object to an instance variable during a list iteration:

```coffee
execute: =>
  while @canExecute()
    for @currentStack in @stacks
      @executeNext()
      if @currentStack.isEmpty()
        @stacks.remove @currentStack
        break
```

The important line here is `for @currentStack in @stacks`.  This assigns `this.currentStack` during iteration. I like this. It makes me happy.

I'm worried though that it's an issue. I don't see it specifically documented anywhere. This code is running in several different products and I haven't found an issue myself. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: What kind of issues are you concerned about?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm not sure. Since it's not documented I'm worried that it's an unintended consequence which hasn't been thought through. When I look at the generated javascript I'm not that concerned. My idea was to see if anyone else is using it and if they've ever had any problems.

Comment: This isn't on-topic for Code Review. Questions about whether a particular piece of code is legal should go to StackOverflow. I'll migrate your question.

Comment: `@currentStack` is a variable like any other so why wouldn't this be legal? Why would you want to drag around temporary state like this though?

Comment: mu is too short: that's what I'm assuming, sounds like there is nothing to worry about. re: temporary state, I need to do this for what I'm trying to accomplish, here is the full context: https://github.com/michaelavila/orc/blob/master/src/orc.coffee ... if you have another approach I am VERY open to changing the way this works, but take a look through the code first. Thanks!

Comment: IMO this is implementation is asking for trouble.
It is certainly prone to a lot of sideeffects that will be hard to debug. You are way to much state I think.
A more functional approach would be much better

Comment: Take a look at the whole file of code I posted a few comments above. If you can figure out how to do this in a functional style I'd be more than happy to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a pure javascript for...in loop, it is perfectly fine you can continue being happy. Link for documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Thanks for the response Eran. This is a little more than a normal for in, because I'm using @ in the variable declaration part of the loop.